Applying PCA Before Training Multiple SVM Binary Classifiers To Reduce Data
I am working on a project which has a goal to determine if a new sample is part of Class A or Class A'. I need multiple of those classifiers. I will have an SVM to classify between:
ClassA - ClassA'   (Class Type A)
ClassB - ClassB'   (Class Type B)
ClassC - CalssC'   (Class Type C)
Etc
From the start, I will already know which class type the data belongs to. For example, I will already know if new data belongs Class type A or B or C, but I will not know if it's ClassA or ClassA'. Which is what the SVM per class type is going to do for me.
The raw data is of shape (1,900), so 900 features for both classes.
I trained an SVM for each class type and I'm getting great results! The issue is that I need to perform inference on a resource constrained embedded system with limited memory.
The SVMs I have trained ends up with about 30 to 100 support vectors depending on the class type. Using a linear kernel. For each class type (A,B,C,etc), I need to store all the support vectors.
For an SVM with 60 support vectors, the data shape I need to store in memory for the support vectors would be (60, 900). Each data point is only 1 byte, so that is 54,000 bytes for a single class type.
I could easily end up having 40+ class types. 40 * 54,000 = 2,160,000 bytes. I need this to fit within 700kB to 800kB. This is where PCA comes in.
I first tried using PCA on each class type. Training the PCA with data from ClassA and ClassA'. Another PCA with ClassB and ClassB', etc. This was able to reduce the size of the support vectors by 70% to 90% without affecting performance! It's fantastic.
But when I dug into how you transform the raw input data to the new PCA space, I found out that the data for the principle components I would need to store to do the transform, needs far more data than I would save by transforming to begin with. If I need to keep 200 principle components, I would need to store a (200, 900) matrix of the principle components! That is 180,000 bytes.
So with PCA (200 principle components) and the SVM (60 support vectors):
PCA needs to store 180,000 bytes = (200,900)
SVM needs to store 12,000 bytes = (60,200)
Total = 192,000 for a single class type.
Without PCA:
SVM needs to store 54,000 bytes = (60,900)
Using PCA actually increased the amount of data I would need to store per class type by 355%! And that does not even include storing the PCA mean and storing the SVM coefficients. Because I need to do the PCA transform on raw data and run inference for the SVM on the embedded system.
Questions:

Is there a way to significantly reduce the data needed for each SVM using PCA?
Is there a way to significantly reduce the data needed for each SVM using some other method?

Possible Solution:
One thing I am trying to answer #1 is to fit a single PCA model for ALL class types. So I run all class data through the PCA and it will choose a new coordinate system for all data. But I feel that is just not as targeted as using PCA for each class type. In this case, PCA will find the vectors with most variance of all data. But PCA per class type would find the vectors with most variance of just ClassA and ClassA' and will maximize the ability to distinguish between them. PCA will pick very different features when train on just one class type as opposed to all class types.
Using one PCA model, will allow me to reduce the size of each SVM and only store a single PCA matrix. And that will reduce data enough theoretically. But before I go down that road. I would like to here some other ideas and thoughts on this issue.

Random Forest has very low overhead.  You can use dbplyr to convert to SQLite3 notation for in-db machine learners on the edge.  You could model-distill into an RF and see if your distilled quality is sufficient.  SQLite3 can beat OS for storage (using fractional blocks) and can be very efficient for execution.  RF is O(n) operations while FFNN and SVM tend to be O(n^5) in inference.
